# Are there consumer-oriented Intel motherboards supporting full 16x PCIe 3.0?

Tags: motherboard, speed, pci-express

I know that many Xeon boards have supported PCIe 3.0 for 16x lane devices for several years now already. However, when I look at [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#cite_note-aggrLink-54) of Intel motherboard chipsets, I only see 16x PCIe 3.0 support beginning with Skylake chipsets, and even that is listed as lower bandwidth than I would expect. Am I misunderstanding the tables? Are there no Intel consumer-grade chipsets supporting full(ish)-speed PCIe 3.0 devices?

On the [Intel ARK website](http://ark.intel.com/), the chipset specs say "PCI Express revision 2.0", but some of the boards appear as PCIe 3.0 nonetheless.

Comment: You should look on Intel's website http://ark.intel.com/#@BoardsAndKits for this information not wikipedia.

Comment: @DavidPostill: See edit.